# One product per registered customer

Tags: product, quantity

Is there a way to limit the quantity of product ordered by a registered customer? We need to limit the amount to one product per customer. We are selling tickets to events.

Comment: are you want for only for register customer

Comment: Yes only for registered customers. We have an extension that hides the product from all other than registered customers.

Answer (score 1):

Webninja.Magento is provide a field name Max by which you can prevent customer cannot purchase one product  one qty at a time

1.`Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart – Minimal quantity customer    must buy` 
2.`Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart – Maximal quantity    customers can buy`

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a legit answer.

Comment: why down vote ,please explain

Comment: I've upvoted you, no reason for a downvote I can see.

Comment: Does this prevent customer from buying the same product again later? We can't have customers buying multiple tickets to the same event in any way. Every member can only order one ticket.

Comment: no,i can only prevent during one checkout